Are there languages that are only demonstrably related within the same family by looking at other languages in the same family?
What I mean is whether there are known languages which, when compared between only themselves, cannot be conclusively shown to be within the same family, but which can be shown to be related when "intermediaries" are brought into the picture. These can be, say, a common ancestor, missing links or sister languages.
Consider, for example, the proposal that Basque and Caucasian languages are related. As it stands, the theory can't be conclusively demonstrated. But if the theory is true then I suppose that once they were the same proto-language and there must have been languages (now forgotten) which could bridge the gap between Basque and the Caucasian languages.
Or imagine if all Indo-European languages except Gaelic and Armenian ended up forgotten - would it still be possible to demonstrate that they're more closely related to each other than to any other language in the world, or would they end up regarded as isolates?

I would say that is what happened with Indo-European.  If we had only had knowledge of English and Hindi, it would have been harder to prove.

@AdamBittlingmayer of course, and I imagine it would be even harder to prove the relationship between Gaelic and Armenian as I proposed, but these are hunches and I'm wondering if there are cases where we more definitely/explicitly know that the relationship between a set of languages can't be demonstrated except by adducing other languages.

It’s hard to prove that something can’t be proved.

@AdamBittlingmayer it's hard, but not impossible, considering that so often language family proposals are marked off as inconclusive (e.g. Basque and Caucasian, or Indo-European and Uralic)

@Mutoh that's not the same thing. Something not being proven (i.e. judged inconclusive) does not mean it's been proven not to be the case. Most linguists agree that a relationship between Indo-European and Uralic hasn't been proven, but also agree that it's plausible, with many believing that it may go on to be proven in the future; a far cry from the relationship having been proven false!

@Tristan I'm not looking for languages which are proven to be unrelated (even that is not impossible; we know Basque is not IE), on the contrary, but for languages which we know are related, only the best demonstration we know doesn't use direct comparison because otherwise it'd be as weak as the comparison between IE and Uralic. E.g. the demonstration shows that A is related to C by proving that A is related to B and B is related to C, because comparing A and C so far had been insufficient. Such a demonstration relies on the "bridge language" B to work.

@Mutoh I know, but my point was to support Adam's claim that it's hard to prove something can't be proven, and to show that your counterargument fails

if you are weakening the requirement for answers to be that the best demonstration requires a third language, rather than that any demonstration requires a third language then the question is opinion based, and not answerable on this site (but such pairs will also be far too numerous to reasonably list here, almost any pair of modern Indo-European languages from different primary branches of IE are best demonstrated to be related via older languages within their respective branches)

@Tristan you can read "best" as state-of-the-art, if you will. A linguist doesn't need to appeal to Latin to show that Portuguese and Spanish are related, even though he could; it would be too roundabout, and therefore it wouldn't be "better" than direct comparison. But my question never demanded such a stringent mathematical-standard concept of impossibility and necessity, in the 1st place. As it stands, IE/Uralic proposals remain unproven (surely they've been proven insufficient), so if we discovered evidence of bridge languages which led to a breakthrough proof it would fit as an answer.

@Tristan only now I saw your edit. "[A]lmost any pair of modern Indo-European languages from different primary branches of IE are best demonstrated to be related via older languages within their respective branches" - that's a very good starting point. Perhaps you could post as an answer with more in-depth information? It would really interest me to see what difficulties linguists have found, it might be precisely what I'm looking for.
